# Soundcloud JavaScript API post comment not working

Tags: javascript, api, soundcloud

I'm using SoundCloud JavaScript SDK to post comment on tracks. It was working well but suddenly it stopped working. I checked their documentation and I'm using exact same code as per their documentation.

Below is my code

```
SC.post("/tracks/" + track_id + "/comments", {
    comment: {
        body: "Awesome track",
        timestamp: 1500
    }
})
```

SoundCloud API Documentation:
https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs#comments
Please check JavaScript tab

Now I'm getting below error

```
code    422
message "Parameter comment is missing."
link    "https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/explorer/open-api"
status  "422 - Unprocessable Entity"
errors  [ {…} ]
0   Object { error_message: "Parameter comment is missing." }
error_message   "Parameter comment is missing."
error   null
```

Please help me how can I resolve this issue.

Thanks